# css centering code doesn't work for same file names in html and css

Tags: html, css

If I use same document name for css and html, css centering code snippet doesn't work. If I change the file name it works.

I use "index" name for css and html both.

I want to understand why is it happening.

Here is example codes;

```css
.maintitle {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintitle">
  <h1>Trial title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the full code of the file you are talking about.

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me share more codes.

Comment: you can edit your question and add all the relevant code you need. You need to show how you link html and css. also you need to show your folder structure. finally, try to refresh the browser cache, this is most probably your issue. You have a cached version of your index.css that is not updated with your last changes. Changing the name will fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility is there is already a file having name index.css, Check for the file name in your project.
You can change the name of both js and css file to some other name (not index) and check if it works or not.
For example change it to demo.js and demo.css

Comment: I m working with django project. There are no other files rather than these files.